# Private nuget feed - package path folders and indexing woes

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, chocolatey, nugetgallery

We used nuget.server 2.8 to create a private feed for hosting nuget packages (mostly chocolatey packages) in our organization. I would like to improve/expand the indexing capability but I can't figure out how to do that.

I know in a typical nuget server feed, all the .NUPKG files would be in the root of the package path specified in the config. Long story short, we have a requirement for a folder structure in that package feed as different groups within the organization will be using SVN to commit data which ends up here. To easily manage this, we need a more complex folder structure.

However what I have found is that .NUPKGs in the root of the package path or one folder deep are indexed and available via the feed. Once you go two folders deep, the NUPKG files aren't indexed and aren't available via the nuget feed. Is there a relatively easy way I can change that? Is that a setting specified somewhere? I can't seem to find where this limitation is coming from. Any direction would be outstanding.

Answer (score 1):

We've had a few users request such a feature for [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget), but ultimately decided against implementing the feature because of the problem of not only dealing with duplicate packages, but communicating that problem to the user.

Remember that a valid NuGet package must have a file name that matches its version+id (e.g. MyPackage.1.2.nupkg can only be MyPackage v1.2). Thus if you have folderA\MyPackage.1.2.nupkg and folderB\MyPackage.1.2.nupkg, which is the valid? Do you invalidate both? Etc.

That said, it's trivial to implement, so you could simply use the ProGet SDK to build your own package store that inherits from the default, but iterates subdirectories as well.

As a side note, if you're serious about maintaining a private repository, you really should get something other than NuGet.Server. There are several available that can manage chocolately packages.

Answer (score 0):

Symlinks is your best bet. You will just want to symlink those files up on a regular basis with a scheduled task.

I have to second Karl's answer on using something better than NuGet.Server. Depending on your growth potential, it can start to become unusable fast after you have 100+ packages in the repository. **Note:** I haven't checked this myself since 2012, it's possible it has better support now for multiple packages.

Comment: What is the best free/open source nuget server available for larger private feeds?

Comment: Nuget gallery is probably going to be a really good one. https://github.com/nuget/nugetgallery